# ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException in 2x3 Transpose matrix

Tags: java, matrix

i am doing matrix transpose,the below code worked for 2x2 Transpose matrix, but it won't working in 2x3 transpose matrix,,kindly help me what mistake i did.

**Exception:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:2

```
package Sep20;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TMatrix {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter the No of rows ");
int row = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the No of coloumn");
int col = in.nextInt();
int first[][]=new int[row][col];
int transpose[][]=new int[col][row];

System.out.println("Enter the matrix");

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j <col; j++) {
first[i][j]= in.nextInt();

}
}
for (int i = 0; i <row; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j <col; j++) 
{
transpose[j][i]=first[i][j];
}
}
System.out.println("Transpose of entered matrix:-");

for (int i = 0; i <row; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j <col; j++) {
System.out.print(transpose[i][j]+"\t");
}
System.out.println();
}
}    
}
```

Comment: never copy and paste code :P

Comment: -1 -- The error message pointed directly at the offending line.  You should have identified that line in your question.

Comment: @FaddishWorm - Nah, no one ever does that.  Or at least Lady Lovelace didn't ... very much.

Answer (score 1):

The transposed matrix is `int[col][row]`, so you have to switch `i` and `j` when printing it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) 
    {
        System.out.print(transpose[j][i]+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println(); // print each row on a new line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now my code work,i forget to change the conditon in the last for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <col; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j<row ; j++) {
System.out.print(transpose[i][j]+"\t");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with printing.

You are converting a 2x3 in a 3x2 correctly by switching the indexes, but you still are trying to print a 2x3 matrix.

Just change the `for` limits

```
for (int i = 0; i <col; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <row; j++) {
        System.out.print(transpose[i][j]+"\t");
    }
}
```

Of course, it is always more helpful if you add the stacktrace and show which is the line that throws the exception.